# jquery toggle panel and auto adjust divs

Tags: jquery, resize, toggle, panel

I have a requirement which uses jquery toggle and resize functionality. I need to display 3 divs in a page. The first div is a side pannel toggle div.

When I toggle side panel div, the other two divs should automatically adjust within the available space. i.e, when the first div is collapsed the second and third div should occupy full page and when first div is expanded the other second and third div should resize and fit in the space available.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this functionality.

Comment: What all you have tried ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS. it is easy.

```
<style scoped>
#mainDiv{ width:100%; height:100%; }
#div1, #div2, #div3 { width:30%; height:30%; }

#div1{ background:black; }
#div2{ background:blue; }
#div3{ background:green; }

#div1:hover,#div2:hover,#div3:hover{ width:100%; height:100px;display:block; }
</style>


<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="div1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="div2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="div3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Adding transformation would solve your problem. you can almost bring it like an itunes currosel in the ipad